# How to make cups to automatically redirect prints that have more than 10 pages to specific printer

Tags: redirect, cups, printing

I have 2 printers on my cups server.
I want that when the print has more than 10 pages, it would be redirected to a specific printer.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Never done this but see `man filter'. It describes cups filters. Maybe you could write your own filter that would detect number of pages and send it to specific printer.

Comment: I didn't find in the man help how to choose only prints that have more than 10 pages.

Comment: I suppose you have to detect it youself, how many pages you are printing. If it would be pdf, there are tools like pdftk, pdfinfo which tell you how many pages the pdf has.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily take advantage of the CUPS load balancing feature. This is done via the "class" feature. Add the two printers to a class and use the class as the print destination. CUPS will distribute jobs evenly between the printers contained within the class.

Comment: I don't want just load balancing. I want that when there will be a print with more than 10 pages, it will go to a specific printer.

Comment: Control it at the user end. Unless you're printing Postscript or PDF documents, the printer/filter won't know how many pages are in the document until printing is already in progress.